# Table is not getting Created in mysql schema from Spring boot JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

I am creating one spring boot application and trying to make a connection with mysql database.

I have created a schema. and trying to add columns in table through spring boot jpa.

Even though my build is geeting passed I am not able to get sucess. I have tried all the possible way fromthe stackover flow but no luck.

Here is my `application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee_management_system?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
```

And this my model class

```
package com.springboot.Model;


import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")

public class Employee {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String  fristName;
    
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(name = "email_id")
    private String emailId;
    
    public Employee() {
        
    }
    
    public Employee(String fristName, String lastName, String emailId) {
        super();
        this.fristName = fristName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }
    
    
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    public String getFristName() {
        return fristName;
    }
    
    
    public void setFristName(String fristName) {
        this.fristName = fristName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getEmailId() {
        return emailId;
    }
    public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }
}
```

Build log : [image: Build Log]

I have doubt on my db connection also. what is the way to debug or findout wheather the spring  it is hitting the schema or not.

Can anybody help me here. This is my first Spring java application.

Comment: Your logs contains one warning. Can you please share that complete warning message with us?

Comment: @pcsutar "spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning"

Comment: @pcsutar I have update in comment. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your `Entity` is under the base package or under the sub-package of base-package? If not, then you need to add it to `Scan` in the main application file:

```
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.springboot.Model"})
```

Try below properties:

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true <br>
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Comment: It works. Actuall packages was not under base packes.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, but all my packages are inside the base package and I have applied all the given solutions but yet tables are not creating

Answer (score 1):

Need to add `createDatabaseIfNotExist=true` parameter in datasource URL as shown in below example:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee_management_system?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false
```

Comment: Two thing i want to add here. 1: Database is already exist. 2. In case if I give new name to database like this `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/new_database?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false` database is getting created but column is still missing in table. But database connection is got established that we sure now.

Comment: Does you main class resides in either ```com.springboot.Model``` or ```com.springboot``` packages?

Comment: Yes, as @Tarun suggest i moved classes and it woked now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization= true` in properties file.